# Prevent phone from sending MouseLeftButtonUp event while scrolling

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone

How can I prevent the windows phone 7 from sending a MouseLeftButtonUp-event to my Grid (that I use as Button) while the user is scrolling?

This issue sometimes leads to a navigation to another page just when the user scrolling.

Or should I use a Button-Template for this?

Example code:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid x:Name="Button1" MouseLeftButtonUp="Button1_LeftMouseButtonUp">
            <TextBlock Margin="12 15" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I used a button with a ControlTemplate instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of LeftMouseButtonUp event try this

```
private void Button1_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.IsInertial)
    {
        //Button Click Code
    }
}
```